# How to manage the security on the SharePoint list

Tags: security, sharepoint-2010

How to manage the security on the list , while one group users can modify all the fields of an item and one group users can only modify some of the fields.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there isn't a way to do this out of the box, so you have to do it in code.  [This discussion at Microsoft's TechNet forum](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/en/sharepointadmin/thread/e2bb0ca1-7a3c-4755-9d4a-00b0bac1d850) talks about some free and pay tools that address this need.

Then again based on your needs you might be able to do something with web forms, i.e. create a form to edit those items that allows one group to edit all fields and another group to only edit some fields.  It's cumbersome since you'd have to create a form for every list you need to restrict at the column level, plus manage permissions, but with this at least you have a functional workaround.